# view.getParent() does not return a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my first Android application, and I want to drag and drop coins into boxes. The onDrag method I found was this:

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) { // onDrag(waarnaartoe, event)
>     if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
>         //  user interface
>         View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
>         ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
>         from.removeView(view); 
>         FrameLayout to = (FrameLayout) v;
>         to.addView(view); 
>         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```

The boxes are LinearLayouts, so I changed the original code i.e.

from

`ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();`  (which works fine)

to

`LinearLayout from = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();`

However, the app crashes if I try to drop something onto a box. The reason I want to get the `LinearLayout` is that I made a `Map` which connects LinearLayouts to `"boxes"` (which are theoretical objects with certain properties).

Could anyone explain to me why I cannot replace `ViewGroup` by `LinearLayout`?

Comment: What is the message when your app is crashing ? If I remember correctly, it would normally say that "Can't cast XXX to LinearLayout"...

Comment: @FR073N It says 'java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout'

Comment: This is your problem : you're using a GridLayout, and trying to cast it to LinearLayout. Are you sure you're using LinearLayout ?

Comment: Hm, I understand the problem now, thanks. I thought the view was in a LinearLayout and the LinearLayout in a GridLayout, but now I'm not sure anymore...

Comment: @Jolien if you know exactly what the issue was and have fixed it, I suggest you answer your own question, by making an answer - this way, if people searches and finds your question, it's gonna be useful for someone else :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function which I copied was not applicable to my program. The line

> FrameLayout from = (FrameLayout) e.getLocalState();

works perfectly fine, so `e.getLocalstate` already gave the container I wanted. Therefore the parent obtained by `view.getParent()` was the `GridLayout`.